# Crear conexiones a un número dinámico de endpoints con wcf

Tags: .net, wcf

estoy intentando hacer una aplicación .net que se conecta a distintos endpoints y ejecute un método, en cada uno de ellos, de un modo dinámico. En concreto: pensemos en que tenemos una tabla con los campos:

- urls de los endpoints (muchos de ellos con wcf)
- método a ejecutar en cada endpoint
- lista de parámatros del método a ejecutar

La pregunta es si, una aplicación .NET, puede crear conexiones dinámicamente a cada uno de los endpoints de la tabla. Sería necesario que la aplicación recorriera la lista de endpoints/métodos/parámetros y fuese realizando las conexiones a cada endpoint para ejecutar el método indicado con sus parámetros.

Ejemplo de tabla:

```
|ID|URL|método|parámetros|

|1|https://www.example.com/service1/math.svc|sumar|1,2,3|
|2|https://www.example.com/service2/Cadenas.svc|concatenar|palabra1,palabra2|
|3|https://www.example.com/serviceN/ServiceN.svc|metodo|param1,param2,param3|
```

En el caso [1] querríamos: conectamos a https://www.example.com/service1/math.svc para ejecutar el método sumar(1,2,3)

Espero haberme explicado (aunque leyendo lo escrito no lo tenga claro).

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas facil para realizar eso es que el servicio WCF este configurado como Rest, y traes json o xml.

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage;
HttpClient client;
HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;
HttpContent content;

public async Task<List<T>> GetAllMovement(string direccion)
    {


        List<T> resultado = new List<T>();
        Uri uri = new Uri(direccion);

        httpResponse = await GetHttpResponse(uri, HttpMethod.Get);
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            content = httpResponse.Content;
            var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);

        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Configuracion de metodo wcf para que sea Rest

```
[WebGet (BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/ConsultarQr/{token}")]
    [OperationContract]
    bool ConsultarQr(string token);
```

Tambien debes configurar el webconfig

```
  <service name="ServicioWCFSeguridad.ServicioQr" behaviorConfiguration="Service">
          <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServicioWCFSeguridad.IServicioQr"/>
          <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServicioWCFSeguridad.IServicioQr" behaviorConfiguration="webRest"/>
        </service>
 </services>

 <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="webRest">
                <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
```